# Finite moment generating function near zero but not subexponential

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

A centered random variable $X$ with moment generating function (MGF) $M_X(t) := \text E[e^{tX}]$ is subexponential if $\log M_X(t) \leq ct^2$ for some $c > 0$ on some neighborhood $(-\delta, \delta)$ of zero.

Are there any examples of random variables with finite MGFs in some neighborhood of zero that are *not* subexponential? Relatedly, how quickly can the MGF grow near zero while still being finite, and, for a given growth rate, how to find a random variable with that MGF?

Answer (score 0):

I think all such functions must be subexponential.  Suppose $M_X$ is finite on some neighborhood of zero, so that there exists $\lambda > 0$ and a constant $C$ so that $M_X(\lambda) \le C$ and $M_X(-\lambda) \le C$.
Then by Markov's inequality for any $t > 0$ we can bound
\begin{align}
\Pr[|X| \ge t] &\le \Pr[X \ge t] + \Pr[X \le -t] \\
&= \Pr[e^{\lambda X} \ge e^{\lambda t}] + \Pr[e^{-\lambda X} \ge e^{\lambda t}] \\
&\le \frac{\mathbf{E}[e^{\lambda X}]}{e^{\lambda t}} + \frac{\mathbf{E}[e^{-\lambda X}]}{e^{\lambda t}} \\
&\le 2Ce^{-\lambda t}
\end{align}
and so $X$ has subexponential tails, hence is subexponential.